# MFC Send message to a button (child to parent)

Tags: c++, button, mfc, parent, sendmessage

I want to send a message from my child window (CDialog) to the parent window (CFormview). If I press the cancel button at the child window, the Dialog should quit and the program should continue with the code of the STOP-Button at the parent Window.

```
void ChildDialog::OnBnClickedCancel()
{
    CDTParentView *pButtonWnd = (CDTParentView *)AfxGetMainWnd();
    pButtonWnd->OnBnClickedbuttonStop();
    CDialogEx::OnCancel();
}
```

but there is an error in this objore.cpp:

```
BOOL CObject::IsKindOf(const CRuntimeClass* pClass) const
{
    ENSURE(this != NULL);
    // it better be in valid memory, at least for CObject size
    ASSERT(AfxIsValidAddress(this, sizeof(CObject)));

    // simple SI case
    CRuntimeClass* pClassThis = GetRuntimeClass(); <------- error

    ENSURE(pClassThis);
    return pClassThis->IsDerivedFrom(pClass);
}
```

Can anyone tell me, whats the problem?
And maybe post a better idea to send the button-clicked message?

Comment: could you tell us which error / error message ?

Comment: And please show the call stack.

Comment: Have you considered learning Windows programming without obscuring it through MFC? You should. It'll teach you a lot of things that are relevant with any framework you use.

Answer (score 5):

Your code isn't actually sending a message, it's trying to call the handler directly. It's easy to simulate the clicking of a button the same way Windows would do it, then your existing code will handle it naturally.

```
CWnd * pMain = AfxGetMainWnd();
CWnd * pButton = pMain->GetDlgItem(ID_STOP_BUTTON);
pMain->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(ID_STOP_BUTTON, BN_CLICKED), (LPARAM)pButton->m_hWnd);
```

Answer (score 1):

AfxGetMainWnd does not return a pointer to the CFormView, it returns a pointer to the CMainFrame.  If your dialog is modal you can simply check the return value of the DoModal call that displays the dialog.  Or you might have better luck with calling GetParent to get a pointer to the CFormView.